# PyTorch value thresholding and zeroing all other values

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have 2D tensor in PyTorch, representing model confidences. I want:

- if 2nd value in row is greater or equal to threshold, all other values should be changed to 0
- else values should not change

The simple approach would be:

- iterate through rows
- check 2nd value
- if value is greater or equal, create row of zeroes, change 2nd value to the 2nd value from row and replace row
- else don't do anything

It is inefficient, however. Is there a vectorized / tensorized way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this by first constructing a new zero matrix, and then moving items from your matrix to the zero matrix as needed. You copy all rows that are in a row whose second element is below the threshold. For all other rows, you only copy the second element.

```py
import torch
threshold = .2

X = torch.rand((100, 10))
new = torch.zeros_like(X)
mask = X[:, 2] <= threshold
new[mask] = X[mask]
new[~mask, 2] = X[~mask, 2]
```

Comment: Great space-time tradeoff, since my solution takes at most O(row_len), but is slow, while yours is a lot faster, but has O(row_len * col_len) memory requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
x[(x[:,1] >= 0.5).nonzero(), np.r_[0, 2:x.shape[1]]] = 0.0
```

First, Get row indices using `(x[:,1] >= 0.5).nonzero()`,
then take columns indices `np.r_[0, 2:x.shape[1]]` except second column.

Comment: But this solution uses numpy, the asker requires torch.

Comment: It's a great solution for CPU, but I'm using PyTorch and GPU and conversions would be too costly. It's good and clean code for Numpy though.